# Preview image before upload. Using the app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I'm new to SE, but it already happened to me. I tried uploading a screenshot to my answer, and i by mistake selected the wrong picture. It wasn't private enough for me to make a big deal about. But I'm sure it happens pretty often that people select the wrong image by mistake and by the time you know it, it's there for the whole world to see!

I know i can remove the picture from the actual post, but it will stay public on imgur.

Can we please have an option to preview the image before uploading to the web while using the SE Android app?

I know this is an option while using a browser, but there is no way to preview the image in the app.

Comment: [Deleting Posts and Images](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/210080953-Deleting-Posts-and-Images)

Comment: @DavidPostill that's what i call a hassle in case that could be very common

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any need for such a feature, because we already have a preview. This is what I see when choosing image to upload from my android device: (LG G4 if it matters)

> [image]

Even better than browser, the images are big and clear. If you need more than that and afraid to misclick, then you really better not upload images to begin with.

In case your device is showing the images in different view, I'm pretty sure it can be changed in the settings, or by installing some app. No need for SE to fix issues of android devices.

One more point, you said "will stay public on imgur". While true, the only way to see such image without any link to it anywhere is guess the random name somehow, which is nearly impossible.

Comment: True, but i believe there should at least be something like a 'confirm' button.

Comment: My LG is better than yours :-P but your weather is warmer than mine.

Comment: @Abochur I don't think so. Like I said, if one is afraid to expose private pictures by mistake, better not upload to begin with.

Comment: @alexolut yeah, today it was almost as warm as during summer, and it should be winter by now. :(

Comment: [Winter is coming](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard i guess we'll have to agree to disagree ;) enjoy the warmth while we freeze here in the us. Happy Chanukah!